# TestNG: How to get class that is about to create by Factory from DataProvider

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a class with `@Factory(dataProvider = "dp")` at constructor.
How can I obtain that class inside data provider?

```
class Test {

   @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
   public Test(int i) {
      //... some code
   }

   @DataProvider
   public static Object[][] dp(ITestContext context, Method method) {
       // need to get currently created class by factory
       // method is null here
       // not found any way to obtain this class from test context
   }

}
```

In this example I can use hardcoded class name, but in real worl data provider is in parent class (or just separated class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
class Test {

   @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
   public Test(int i) {
      //... some code
   }

   @DataProvider
   public static Object[][] dp(ConstructorOrMethod com) {
       Class<?> testClass = com.getConstructor().getDeclaringClass();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Julien, I'll try it! Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Not yet: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1143 But feel free to propose an improvement on the documentation :D

Comment: @SergeyIrisov Is my answer correct according to your question? If yes, could you accept it?